# r heatmap custom scale

Tags: r, plot, heatmap

How to define colour scale on heatmap from base R?

For instance I have two heatmaps:

```
heatmap(as.matrix(data.frame(a=c(1,2),b=c(2,0))), scale="none")
heatmap(as.matrix(data.frame(a=c(1,4),b=c(2,0))), scale="none")
```

But I want the first want to be scaled from 0 to 4 rather than from 0 to 2.

I couldn't quite get that from the documentation. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to hack the `heatmap()` function to do what you want (it isn't possible with the function as-is).

But! you can do this pretty easily with the `image()` function (which is used internally by `heatmap()`), by specifying the `zlim` argument:

```
image(as.matrix(data.frame(a=c(1,2),b=c(2,0))), zlim=c(0, 4))
```

Comment: Thanks, although I was hoping to maintain all heatmap features, i.e. dendrogram, coloured bar on the axes... I guess I need to do some tweaking of the original heatmap.